# Importing a winmail.dat file into my calendar using Thunderbird Lightning

Tags: email, calendar, thunderbird, lightning, winmail.dat

I am using Thunderbird with the Lightning extension to organize my calendars. As it is very common to send around winmail.dat files to quickly import a new event to a calendar, I am faced with the issue to use this winmail.dat file to do so.

Has anybody found a way to do this in a comfortable way? What I **don't** want is to download the winmail.dat file first, convert it with some (online) tool and then be able to import it. It has to be a **direct and very quick way** as otherwise I would prefer to create the event entry manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [LookOut add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/thunderbird/addon/lookout/) will handle decoding of winmail.dat files.

Comment: I meanwhile already tried to use the LookOut add-on. It gave me two additional files to the winmail.dat file. One of them was the .rtf-file but the other one was not the .ics-file but a file called "Untitled Attachment". Are you using LookOut and it works for you to receive a winmail.dat file and include the event in your calendar? Would be very happy to receive more information from you!

PS: I am using Thunderbird 24.4.0 with Lookout 1.2.13 under openSUSE Linux.

Comment: I haven't had the need to use it myself, no.

Comment: It becomes even worse if you have the Thunderbird Conversation Plugin installed. Then, the winmail.dat file does not seem to get converted at all...